# Missing "find options" in Xcode 3.2

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Generally speaking, I am very happy with the changes in Xcode 3.2. However, there is one thing which is driving me crazy: the "find in file" dialog has been jettisoned for the "find banner."  But what is missing in this nifty little banner are the good-old options: starts-with, contains, whole-word, ignore-case, &c

On my dev machine, the find banner *always* uses case-sensitive and whole-word options, which is a pain… I tried changing these settings in the "project find" dialog, but they did not carry over into the 'find in file' banner.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you prefer to search with the banner, you can drop down the little arrow next to the magnifying glass to get the options you want in the banner.

If you want the old-style window, Apple-Shift-F brings up the Project-Find dialog that has all those options.

Comment: thx rein! since I've modified my key-bindings from the 'metrowerks compatible' preset, the cmd-shift-F doesn't work for me... strange that I can't find a menu-item for this feature. 
but the magnifying glass menu is precisely what I was looking for, thanks!
|K<

Comment: You can also modify the key bindings (Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings) by expanding Edit, Find and assigning ⌘F to "Find and Replace...", which I find more useful than "Find..." in the general case.